# lookup user in ActiveDirectory by email address

Tags: c#, active-directory

How can I query an ActiveDirectory user by email address? A given user can have multiple emails such as both john.smite@acme.com and jsmith@acme.com. For a given email, how can I get back the A/D user?

I'm programming in C#.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can search your AD with following code:

```
    DirectoryEntry adEntry = null;

    private void SetADInfoAndCredentials()
    {
        adEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + ad_textBox.Text);
        adEntry.Username = user_textBox.Text;
        adEntry.Password = pw_textBox.Text;
    }

    private void SearchForMailInAD()
    {
        DirectorySearcher adSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(adEntry);
        adSearcher.Filter = ("mail=" + mail_textBox.Text);
        SearchResultCollection coll = adSearcher.FindAll();
        foreach (SearchResult item in coll)
        {
            foundUsers_listBox.Items.Add(item.GetDirectoryEntry());
        }
    }
```

€: This will search for the mail address in proxyAddresses which hosts all mail addresses

```
    public static SearchResultCollection FindAccountByEmail(string pEmailAddress)
    {
        string filter = string.Format("(proxyaddresses=SMTP:{0})", email);

        using (DirectoryEntry gc = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP:"))
        {
            foreach (DirectoryEntry z in gc.Children)
            {
                using (DirectoryEntry root = z)
                {
                    using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(root, filter, new string[] { "proxyAddresses", "objectGuid", "displayName", "distinguishedName" }))
                    {
                        searcher.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.All;
                        SearchResultCollection result = searcher.FindAll();

                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you - Second code set works great. When would I want to use the first (LDAP) approach? And what goes after LDAP://?

Comment: First code would only work of know exactly which primary mail address is defined. After Ldap you have to can set your domain or your controller

Comment: Why do you use a foreach loop? You return a value in the first iteration.

Comment: How did you figure out you have to use the filter `mail=`? Doesn't AD store emails under `E-mail`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I am missing something here, but finding an AD user from an e-mail address can be done much simpler:

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, emailAddress);
```

Comment: for me, this works only with username but not with email. Why?

Comment: Because it doesn't work with email I don't know why someone upvoted this.

Comment: Well, it obviously did for me. Could it be because the AD I was working with uses the e-mail address as UPN?